# Not able to release view Controller/ cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios

I think this is weird but same code was working fine for me in other application So, I am overriding my function in iphone app delegate which inherits Super class that is Main delegate

```
       * .appdelegate_iPhone.h *
        @interface AppDelegate_iPhone : AppDelegate 
        {

        }

        @end

    * .appdelegate_iPhone.m *
........

        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {
          LoginViewController_iPhone * login_view = [[LoginViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
                [super.window addSubview:login_view.view];
                [super.window makeKeyAndVisible];
               //[login_view release];


            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
            return YES;

        }
......
@end
```

As you can see that i commented out releasing login_view because if i don't and release the object, I am not able to Control any IBoutlet UIField after.

I mean if i release login_view and try to use UITextField.text, i get exc_bad_access error

Comment: Where do you init the login_view?

Comment: LoginViewController_iPhone * login_view  = [[LoginViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];  ,gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize the view controller. The iOS allocated space for the view controller but you did not initialized it.

```
LoginViewController_iPhone * login_view  = [[LoginViewController_iPhone alloc] init];
```

And why are you calling `[super.window addSubview:login_view.view];`
 and not `[window addSubview:login_view.view];` ?

The super of your appDelegate is a [NSObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it does not have an window property.

Comment: I am initiazlizing it as `code LoginViewController_iPhone * login_view = [[LoginViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil]; `   Plus i have Universal app, so my super for this class is not NSOBject, it is Main delegate which i am inheriting in iPad and iPhone delegate

Answer (score 0):

First, using the built-in templates and its nib file generally makes all of this much simpler, and I highly recommend that rather than trying to build it this way. That said, let's talk about what's happening.

You're creating a view controller, then taking its view out and putting it in the window. You're then throwing away the view controller, which correctly deallocates. I don't know where you would call `UITextField.text`, but by the time this method completes, the view controller should be gone. If you want to hold onto the view controller, you need to put it in an ivar.

As @Cyupa notes, you should not be using `super.window` here. You should be using `self.window`, though ideally you should use one of the templates instead if you can.

Comment: I just updated the code to explain it better why i m using super.window , not self.window because this class doesnt't have UIWindow. Super class (appDelegate) which is universal appdelegate for iPhone and iPad has UIWindow that i am calling from this iPhone_delegate class.

Comment: My LoginViewController is like this  `code @interface LoginViewController_iPhone : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet  UITextField * usernameField; } `